# is the formula of cdf of standard normal distribution in nist wrong?

Tags: integration

this formula comes from [nist](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3661.htm)

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

which is different from this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) version

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{-t^{2}/2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}} dt
$$

is the nist version wrong? or it is appropriate way to write a integral formula omitting dt?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a $dt$. Also, the variable of integration should be something other than $x$ (since $x$ is used as the argument of $F$). But it can be pretty much anything else, like $a,y,u$, etc. So you could also write $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\, dy,$$ for example. (The variable of integration is a "dummy variable".)